# Make a js request with 2 methods POST and PUT

Tags: angularjs, django-rest-framework-jwt

I got api for creating cats with authorisation token

```
curl -X POST -H "Authorization: JWT <dat_token>" -X PUT -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"name":"SuperApi2","breed":"Bite"}' http://127.0.0.1:8000/cats/api/
```

how to write request in AngularJs for this operation? It has 2 methods POST and PUT

I tried to play with something like this but it does not work

```
var req = {
    method: 'POST',
    url:'http://127.0.0.1:8000/cats/api/',
    headers: {
        'Authorization':'<data_token>',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    data: {"name":"AngularJs","breed":"Bite"}
};
$http(req).then(
    function(qwe) { console.log(qwe) }, 
    function(error) { alert(error.toSource()) }
);
```

Comment: why you put two method types in your curl command? that doesn't mean to me. You are trying two make two http requests at same type in just on request?

Comment: @RezaTorkamanAhmadi I am just amateur, but for a strange reason, curl command need 2 methods (1 bugs). But 2 methods are ok. The function has only put method.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, this operation does not really need POST method, only put

```
var req = {
    method: 'PUT',
    url:'http://127.0.0.1:8000/cats/api/',
    headers: {
        'Authorization':'<data_token>',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    data: {"name":"AngularJs","breed":"Bite"}
};
$http(req).then(
    function(qwe) { console.log(qwe) }, 
    function(error) { alert(error.toSource()) }
);
```